# How to deal with conflicting lib.so in linux system and anaconda

Tags: c++, linux

Does anyone know how to make sure the libraries in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `~/anaconda3/envs/zedcv/lib/` can be ensured to be same ? What I want is a way I can use sudo apt install or something...
For example `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`
and `~/anaconda3/envs/zedcv/lib/libc.so.6`
I get error when I try to run an app ZEDfu , bcz it tries to use some .so files from `~/anaconda3/envs/zedcv/lib/` and some from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: The whole point is to be able to have them be different without either affecting the other. The app should be built in such a way that it uses only the anaconda libraries or only the system libraries.

Comment: But its a binary executable, that I am just running. I cannot change it. So that's why I am looking at being able to have same versions systemwide